# Separate database for active record versioning using paper trail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to log the change events of a model in a separate database using papertrail.

I'm using Rails 4.1.2

Ruby 2.1

Papertrail 4.0.0

Below is the code i have added in concerns

```
module Foo
 class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
 end

 class Version < Base
  include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
 end

 class Topic < Base
  has_paper_trail class_name: 'Foo::Version'
 end
end
Foo::Base.establish_connection(:trail_development)
```

I have included this Foo in topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Foo
end
```

Whats wrong?

Reference https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/pull/289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at some of the `tests` within the `paper_trail` gem I found an `example spec` that tests what you are trying to achieve: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/v3.0.0/spec/support/alt_db_init.rb